# Is appropriate to use map(func, list) to transform objects without returning a list?

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I have a "best practices" question here.  I am using map in a way that it may not be intended to be used - using the elements of a list to change the state of a different object.  the final list output is not actually changed.  Is this appropriate?

For example:

```
 class ToBeChanged(object):
      def __init__(self):
           self.foo_lst = [1,2,3,4]
      def mapfunc(self, arg):
           if arg in ['foo', 'bar']:
               self.foo_lst.append(arg)
           else:
               pass

 test = ToBeChanged()
 list_to_map = [1,2,37,'foo']

 map(lambda x: test.mapfunc(x), list_to_map)
```

Comment: Read these 2 and you'll have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not appropriate. In Python 2, you'll be creating a new list of the same length as `list_to_map`, and immediately discarding it; waste! And the `lambda` even makes it more complicated.

Better to use a for loop:

```
for x in list_to_map:
    test.mapfunc(x)
```

More concise and readable.

And if you're still thinking of using this in Python 3 (by forcing the *lazy object* to be evaluated in some way), consider those who will maintain your code; `map` gives the impression you want to create a new iterable from the list.

Comment: Good point; but in python 3, will calling map generate that new list?

Comment: But in Python 3, it's the for loop that'll do more work; waste! :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann this is exactly why I posed this question - I used map because I was under the impression that it[map] does less work; furthermore it is only a one line solution

Comment: @JayStanley Um... yeah, it does NO work. It won't call your function at all!

Comment: @StefanPochmann I just tested it and you're correct.  Why does the change not apply? What special case is the map function doing here that prevents changing the object's state? I was under the impression that map applies a function to an iterable; the literal interpretation of this (to me) would imply that test.foo_lst should change.   It does not

Comment: @JayStanley: because of Python-3's lazyness, it will not do much (in fact it will not call the function on the elements until the result is consumed somehow).

Comment: @JayStanley `map` gives you an iterator that goes to work when it's iterated. But you're not iterating it, you're just throwing it away.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I understand iterators/generators a lot more deeply now.  Very cool; when I change the expression to list(map(lambda x: test.mapfunc(x), list_to_map)), foo_lst changes. If I don't iterate over the map, then the function isn't applied.  Cool!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the the `itertools` `consume` recipe as an option (although often seems like overkill) https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Answer (score 2):

map is the worst.

Because if you tried to run the code in python3 it wouldn't even perform the calls since in python3 map is lazy.

In any case both calling map or a list-comprehension are expressions and expressions should be as side-effect free as possible, their purpose is to return a value.

So if you don't have a value to return you should just use the plain statements: i.e. explicit for