# What is more efficient ? Using Map or For loop in python ?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

Assume that I am writing test code. Now there are two ways of doing the same thing, for the sake of good and efficient coding practice, I would like to know which one is better/smarter ?

first example:

```
    for hardware_id in (someInterface.HardwareEnum):
      DummyFunction(hardware_id, some_parameter_enum)
```

Second Example:

```
    map(lambda hardware_id: DummyFunction(hardware_id, some_parameter_enum), someInterface.HardwareEnum)
```

Comment: First one. Don't use `map` unless you're actually trying to map something. Second one won't even run the `DummyFunction` in Python 3.

Comment: If the section is truely performance critical, you should benchmark both options and use the one which is faster. Normally though, you should use the option which better conveys your meaning, which probably is the first option. Always remember that your code is primarily for people, not machines.

Comment: This could help: [Is appropriate to use map(func, list) to transform objects without returning a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226067/is-appropriate-to-use-mapfunc-list-to-transform-objects-without-returning-a-l/42226154#42226154)

Comment: There is a more important question -- is your function returning something? You would typically use map to transform a list of values to another **via the mapping function**. Typically such functions are *pure functions*.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan No the function is not returning anything, it is supposed to just transform some values in a list.

Comment: @HolgerJust good point. Code is primarily for people, not machines. Serves as an answer for me. Readability is important if the situation is not perfromance critical.

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards the existing answers

Comment: @RoshanGupta: The point of `map(..)` is to transform items in the list. If the function doesn't return anything then it is most likely causing some *side-effect*. In this case, map is not supposed to be used. Plain old for-loop is better.